# How to count unique value from the column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

| How many times it has been repeated - A column | Value to count repetition - B column |
| --- | --- |
| x | ac9987677768776 |

As on the example above, I want to display how many times the *"Value to count repetition"*, counted with entire B column in mind, occurred. The number should appear instead of the "x" in the *"How many times it has been repeated - A column"*.

Would you be kind enough to help me out?

Cheers!

Comment: UNIQUE combined with COUNTIF

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(B2:B; B2:B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY(B2:B,"select B, count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B) ''")
```